# How to install Python into Windows Docker container

Tags: python, docker

I want to create a docker container using base image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8.1` but I also need Python on here. Unfortunately the official Python images only use `windowsservercore`. What do I put in my Dockerfile to make this happen? All the documentation I see are either for linux/unix or require manually downloading an exe beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Something I have tried successfully is installing the python interpreters using chocolatey. First I setup the chocolatey service in the container:

```
ENV ChocolateyVersion=1.2.1
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

Then in a separate layer

```
RUN choco install -y python2
```

(don't ask why I am still needing to install py2, I am not happy about it either :D )

This adds some overhead, but that could be managed by cleaning up C:\ProgramData\chocolatey before finishing the container setup.